# Button icons not getting displayed

Tags: jquery, css, html, kendo-ui

When I use Kendo UI elements, button icons are not getting displayed. It happens for all elements (like grid, ajax window etc). I guess that I should attach a default folder to my project but I don't know the exact path.

This is my header section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/admin.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: remove `/` from the 3rd `link`

Comment: removed.but nothing changed.

Comment: add the `jquery.min.js` script just before the closing `body` tag

Comment: unfortunatly all elemets disabled by this action!

Comment: If that is the case then I'll have to ask you to make a fiddle

Comment: thanks.but i can't use jsfiddle in this case.but this is a link that i use: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/ajax

Comment: I made it! it should add default folder to style folder of project.thank you my friend!

Comment: I have corrected capitalization and grammar issues in the content, removed thanks note as it is not required (fluff). I have also removed the framework name from the title because it is not required due to presence of tags.

Answer (score 1):

Icons are not visible because you have not added images in your project. You can also download all the images from the telerik site or from this [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=977B16A5E89A5236!269&authkey=!AECVuLBgjfSy4ks&ithint=file%2Crar)(Older version images).

As per the CSS file code we have to put the CSS file and image folder on the same level/directory.  Please check the below screenshot for reference.
[image]

Let me know if any concern.